# How to modify this script to run either in pieces...to not consume all my memory?

Tags: powershell, zip, out-of-memory, powershell-3.0

I am running into a small problem, the scenario is like this : 13.300 folders which each have 20 .zip files in it with different content. I need to find the ones which have .txt files in it and then delete them BUT keep the latest X in every of the 13.300 folders.

But first I want to check how many zip files I have all in all which contain a .txt file.

The script looks like this :

```
# the .zip files are in the 13.300 folders which are in "c:\topfolder"

$motherfolder = "c:\topfolder"
$childfolder = Get-Childitem "c:\topfolder"

$searchTerms = @( ".txt")
function openZip($zipFile){
    try{
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" ) | Out-Null;
        $zipContens = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile);  
        $zipContens.Entries | % {
            foreach($searchTerm in $searchTerms){
                if ($_.Name -imatch $searchTerm){
                    Write-Output ($_.Name + "," + $_.FullName + "," + $_.CompressedLength + "," + $_.LastWriteTime + "," + $_.Length);
                }
            }               
        }
    }
    catch{
        Write-Output ("There was an error:" + $_.Exception.Message);
    }
}  

foreach ($childfolder in $motherfolder) {
Get-ChildItem  $zipfolder -recurse *.zip | sort modifyTime -desc | select -skip 2  {
    openZip $_.FullName  >> "C:\Projects\PSScripts\report.csv"
    }
}
```

When this script runs on the server it takes ages and eats all the memory, so what's the best way to modify this ? first let the script only check the first maybe 500 folders instead of 13.300 ? and than another  500 etc.?
It's the first time that I encounter this problem...

Comment: Can you use something else, like 7Zip, to look into zip files? Is plain .Net a requirement?

Comment: yes we can take 7zip, that's not a problem. we have .net 4.5 on that machine that's why I went for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem Identification

Since you are reading files and interacting with them with compression programs,
your problem is not memory, it is:

- Disk speed (file IO)
- CPU / Processing power (compressing/uncompressing)

#### Proposed Solution

I suspect you would see a significant performance increase if you were using SSDs... and even more in a [RAID 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID_1#RAID_1) configuration.

#### Alternative Solutions

You could run a schedule, in downtime, to **cache** the contents of all the files you need to read and load the cached information into memory when performing your checks/searches.
This way, the IO is done upfront in one go and the rest is done in RAM, which is much faster.

Comment: thank you, i actually "fixed" it by just taking a maximum of 1000items and perform the action on this. then i run it again for the next 1000 items etc etc.